# Struggling with an api call and getting data from the api to display in browser

Tags: javascript, html, api

I need to recreate a simple product details page, using an API. It's not something I have ever done so I am struggling a bit.

I have managed to fetch the API but I can't figure out how to extract the data I need for the browser. I have been watching YouTube videos but I can't seem to come right.

this is my call to the API, honestly not even sure if this is correct, the data does show up in my console.

```
*fetch("https://fe-assignment.vaimo.net/").then((data) => {
      // console.log(data);
      return data.json();
      }).then((completedata) => {
      console.log(completedata);
      }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
      });*
```

then for example I want to be able to access the image:

```
*<img class="drone" src=`${product.gallery[0]}`>*
```

but I am just getting errors.

If anyone can able point me to some documentation or tutorials I would be incredibly great fall

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any framework or pure javascript? Jquery? If pure javaScript, you have to get the img class="drone" and append your images there. if you are using any framework, then the solution might be different.